# number theory RSA encryption problem 2

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers and $N =pq$. Do multiplication $\mod N$. Define $G $= {natural numbers less than $pq$ that are relatively prime to $pq$} and $s =(p-1)(q-1)$ . Then

$(1)$ $m^s =1 $ for all $m$ in $G$.

I have no clue with first part of this problem, and don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Have you heard of Euler's totient theorem?

Comment: No, my professor has never mentioned that theorem in class, and therefore I think it can be solved without using that theorem.

Comment: What about Fermat's Theorem?

Comment: Yeah, we have learned Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: By Fermat's Theorem, we have $m^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Taking the $(q-1)$-th power of both sides, we find that $m^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Similarly, $m^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.  Now can you finish?